# при вызове диалога всегда была активная кнопка родителя QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

хочу сделать одну фичу. есть родительское окно и на нем к примеру расположенные 4 кнопки. когда кликаешь 1 кнопку вызывается диалоговое окно... ну так при вызове диалога окно родительское окно становится неактивным (т.е. родительское окно темнеет и не реагирует на событие пользотеля). я хочу сделать так что бы 2 кнопка родительского окна была актиной (т.е. реагировал на событие пользователя) и остальные кнопки родительского окна как положено не были актиными. все это хочу сделать в QML.
Вот код

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10

        Dialog {
            id: dialog
            title: "Blue sky dialog"

            contentItem: Rectangle {
                color: "lightskyblue"
                implicitWidth: 400
                implicitHeight: 100
                Text {
                    text: "Hello blue sky!"
                    color: "navy"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button1"
            onClicked: {
                dialog.open()
            }
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button2"
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button2"
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button2"
        }
    }
}
```

Есть родительское окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нажимаем кнопку 1 открывается диалоговое окно и родителькое окно становится неавтивным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы кнопка 2 была активным когда отображается диалоговое окно ?

Comment: Покажите, что сделали и что не получается. В противном случае Ваш вопрос пойдёт в утиль.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, используя модальный диалог это сделать нельзя(не используя C++, но не факт, что если даже полезть в C++, то получится нормальное решение). Модальный диалог предназначен для того, чтобы пользователь не мог достучаться ни до каких окон, кроме модального.

Таким образом первым шагом нам надо убрать модальность. За это отвечает свойство `modality` у `Dialog`. Затем нам нужно сделать все кнопки кроме 2-й неактивными, когда диалог показывается. Для этого нужно использовать свойство `visible` у `Dialog` и `enabled` у `Button`.

В результате получим такой код:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 10

        Dialog {
            id: dialog
            title: "Blue sky dialog"

            modality: Qt.NonModal
            contentItem: Rectangle {
                color: "lightskyblue"
                implicitWidth: 400
                implicitHeight: 100
                Text {
                    text: "Hello blue sky!"
                    color: "navy"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button1"
            enabled: !dialog.visible
            onClicked: {
                dialog.open()
            }
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            text: "button2"
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            enabled: !dialog.visible
            text: "button3"
        }

        Button {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            enabled: !dialog.visible
            text: "button4"
        }
    }
}
```